# I am getting the error in Java : cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, oop

I am running this code and getting the error in

```
System.out.print(name[i]+" ");
System.out.print(age[i]+" ");
System.out.print(country[i]+" ");
```

that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    name cannot be resolved to a variable
    age cannot be resolved to a variable
    country cannot be resolved to a variable
```

how can I resolve this problem?

```
public class AnyInteger
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws FileNotFoundException
   
 {
        int n = 0;
         
try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Java\\eclipse-workspace\\AnyInteger\\src\\file.txt"));
        
String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine())!= null) {
            String[] arr =str.split("#");
            n = arr.length;
            String name[] = new String[n];
            int age[] = new int[n];
            String country[] = new String[n];
            int i=0;
            while(i<n)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                {
                    name[j] = arr[i];
                    i = i+1;
                    age[j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                    i = i+1;
                    country[j] = arr[i];
                    i = i+1;
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }

catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Read Error");
    }
  
    
    System.out.println("Names: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(name[i]+" ");
    }
    
     System.out.println("Ages: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(age[i]+" ");
    }
    
     System.out.println("Countries: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(country[i]+" ");
    }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: names array is a local variable to while loop, it can not be used outside while loop

Comment: likewise `age` and `country`.

Comment: Then how should I correct it, please suggest

Comment: Show an example of your input

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the arrays `name[]`, `age[]` and `country[]` outside of try/catch statment and just instantiate it in `while` loop if you want.

Something like this:

```java
public class AnyInteger
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws FileNotFoundException
   
 {
        int n = 0;
        String name[];
        int age[];
        String country[];
         
try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Java\\eclipse-workspace\\AnyInteger\\src\\file.txt"));
        
String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine())!= null) {
            String[] arr =str.split("#");
            n = arr.length;
            name = new String[n];
            age = new int[n];
            country = new String[n];
            int i=0;
            while(i<n)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                {
                    name[j] = arr[i];
                    i = i+1;
                    age[j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                    i = i+1;
                    country[j] = arr[i];
                    i = i+1;
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }

catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Read Error");
    }
  
    
    System.out.println("Names: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(name[i]+" ");
    }
    
     System.out.println("Ages: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(age[i]+" ");
    }
    
     System.out.println("Countries: ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(country[i]+" ");
    }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: It is now showing runtime error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails to compile, because variables `name, age, country` are out
of scope, but

something like this should work (not tested)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AnyInteger {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int n = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Java\\eclipse-workspace\\AnyInteger\\src\\file.txt"));

            String str;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = str.split("#");
                n = arr.length;
                String name[] = new String[n];
                int age[] = new int[n];
                String country[] = new String[n];
                int i = 0;
                while (i < n) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        name[j] = arr[i];
                        i = i + 1;
                        age[j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                        i = i + 1;
                        country[j] = arr[i];
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                    printMyStuff(name, age, country, n);
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }

    }

    private static void printMyStuff(String[] name, int[] age, String[] country, int n) {


        System.out.println("Names: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(name[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("Ages: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(age[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("Countries: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(country[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Usually, using static methods is not a good idea, but this should be ok for starters.

Comment: It is now showing runtime error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the names,age and country outside the while loop and instantiate the name,age and country once you get to know the value of 'n'(inside while loop).

your code should be changed in the following way :

```
    String[] name ;
    int[] age;
    String[] country;
    
    while ((str = in.readLine())!= null) {
        String[] arr =str.split("#");
        n = arr.length;
        name = new String[n];
        age = new int[n];
        country = new String[n];    
        
    }
```

**NOTE :** And to avoid ArrayOutOfBound Exception just ensure the n value is always greater than or equal to the number 3 that you used in the for loop used inside while.

Comment: can you please help me by rewriting the code? I am unable to understand the changes as I am a novice, trying my best to understand concept of java.

Comment: // Providing the answer in 2 comments as I dont have enough space 
// Irrespective of the logic , providing you the code that works fine.
//Lets assume n = 2
name = new String[n]; // name's array length will be 2. So it will be having only 2 indexes.starting from 0 and 1
age = new int[n];  //  age array's length will be 2. 
country = new String[n];    // country array's length will be 2
int i=0;

Comment: while(i<n) { // based on the condition , if i = 0 and n = 2 , the while will run only 2 times
 // this for loop will execute 3 times.If n is 2 and you if you're iterating it for 3 times.you will get ArrayOutOfbound Exception.So Instead of 3 use the variable 'n' in the for loop.
 // for(int j=0;j<3;j++)    Commenting your condition and re-writing it again.
 for(int j=0 ; j < n ; j++){
  name[j] = arr[i];  
  i = i+1;
  age[j] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
  i = i+1;
  country[j] = arr[i];
  i = i+1;
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a sample of your input file (file.txt)? That would help provide the most appropriate solution.